# Not able to use a jQuery plugin with Angular 4 and Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-webpack-starter

I'm using Angular 4 with webpack and I'm not able to use a jQuery plugin,with angular cli it works,with webpack not

I've included the plugin in webpack.config.vendor.js

```
const treeShakableModules = [
   .....
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
    'virtual-keyboard',
```

If i check the source page at

```
script src="/dist/vendor.js?v=SsiHzOEk9BPk3CnH6ivS_kkChKmOOxXsB-fFyDO1R8w"></script>
```

I can find the js plugin code

In my .ts code I have

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
....
$('#mycontrol').css('background-color', 'red');// I see the change so jQuery works
(<any>$('#mycontrol')).keyboard();
```

In console I got this error:
**$(...).keyboard is not a function**

with angular cli works very simple with this code

```
declare var $: any;
 $('#mycontrol').keyboard();
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can import it inside your component like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

anf of course import jquery.js in angular-cli.json

Comment: thanks.I have no angular-cli.it is only webpack(webpack.config.js) .now how to import my plugin file,located in node_modules?

Comment: in your  webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
        }
    }
};

Comment: or you can use the [imports-loader](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/integrating-jquery-chosen-with-webpack-using-imports-loader/)

Comment: I have 2 files webpack.config.js and webpack.config.vendor.js. Inside  webpack.config.js  I have 2 resolve:   sections.   But where to put my plugin.js file?.thanks

Comment: I've loaded jQuery successfully. I've included my plugin in webpack.config.vendor.js at const treeShakableModules =[...]   but function inside are not recognized:   $(...).mymethod is not a function

Comment: ufff... I've used tis code   import * as $ from "jquery";
import "virtual-keyboard";   and plugin started to work but it gives me this error : "Error: jQuery requires a window with a document",after 3 refreshes of the page error is gone...

Comment: please add this line to your webpack config :  window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

Comment: Hi.I put it on webpack.config.js  now i got  AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (window is not defined
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (..webpack.config.js:6:2)

Comment: ok add this to ebpack config  "new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
})"  and delete jquery from alias and try again please

Comment: I already have this line   webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', 'window.jQuery': 'jquery' }),

Comment: I have 2 files webpack.config.vendor.js and webpack.config.js,none contain alias.thanks

Answer (score 1):

first you should to add it webpack config :

```
 plugins: [

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.pt'
        }),


        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        }),

    ]
```

after in your component you can import it :

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

this is a global solution access to jquery then several options exist.

of course don't forget to install jquery via npm :

```
npm i --save jquery
```

Comment: Hi.I've edited my first post because I successfuly included jQuery,but now now I got error on plugin functions.thanks

Comment: add in resolove section a new alias resolve: {
    alias: {
         jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
    },

Comment: or there are another way to put $ as a global context like that :                   var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;

Comment: hi,I have 2 sections,I've added after the first  , extensions: [ '.js' ], 
        alias: { jquery: "jquery/src/jquery" }  but now got this error: NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined      on second solution :    Property '$' does not exist on type 'Window'

Comment: lots of test but ending with this error  $(...).keyboard is not a function